# Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_create.so

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the [Explore the Gazebo world](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/indigo/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world) tutorial of turtlebot_simulator in ROS Indigo. Whenever I try to launch roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch I get the following error

```
Error [Plugin.hh:156] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_create.so: libgazebo_ros_create.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control installed. What do I do to fix this?

Edit:
I have also tried [compiling from source](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203558/failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros_create.so/) by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing [turtlebot_create_desktop](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_create_desktop) from source solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) with karma: 71 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isankad1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/31223/isankad1990/) on 2017-07-17**:
i tried this one but still i face this problem Do you have any solution????

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-08**:
@isankad1990 if this didn't solve your issue you should ask a new question. The answerer (who also asked the question) clearly marked this answer as correct for them.